# Firefox rendering gone WRONG - see something really weird

Tags: html, firefox, rendering, firebug

I have the following is really weird. Bassically when I view the source of the page everything looks fine but the page looks all wrong. So I decided to take a look at the source using firebug and firebug shows a very different story. But if I refresh the page the page looks fine and the source and firebug match up.

See below for what the source is but what firefox displays and firebug shows:

View source shows this:

```
<div class="mainpanel">  
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Little-Rock"> 
        <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB001D_0.jpg" alt="Little Rock" /></td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="thumbphototitle">Little Rock</div> 
    </a>  
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Split-Rock"> 
        <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB002D_0.jpg" alt="Split Rock" /></td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="thumbphototitle">Split Rock</div>
    </a>  
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Rock-Pointer"> 
        <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB003D_0.jpg" alt="Rock Pointer" /></td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="thumbphototitle">Rock Pointer</div>
    </a>   
</div>
```

But firebug shows this and it renders on the screen as if its like this:

```
<div class="mainpanel">  
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Little-Rock"> 
        <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB001D_0.jpg" alt="Little Rock" /></td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="thumbphototitle">Little Rock</div> 
    </a>  

    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Split-Rock"></a> 
    <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB002D_0.jpg" alt="Split Rock" /></td></tr></table></div>
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Split-Rock"> </a> 
    <div class="thumbphototitle">
        <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Split-Rock">Split Rock</a>
    </div> 
    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Split-Rock"> </a> 

    <a class="thumbphoto" onclick="window.location=this.href;return false;" href="/Photograph/Narooma/Rock-Pointer"> 
        <div class="thumbphotoimage"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="/Assets/Photos/Portfolio/BB003D_0.jpg" alt="Rock Pointer" /></td></tr></table></div>
        <div class="thumbphototitle">Rock Pointer</div>
    </a>   
</div>
```

The offending html is the middle a tag which goes crazy...

Any ideas.

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: totally unrelated to your question, but why are the images wrapped in a table, and why is there an `onclick` listener for the anchors that pretty much just says "just do what anchors normally do" ?

Comment: Long story but its the only way that I could get the images to align both horizontally and vertically... I tried 1000 different ways and in the end this is the only way that worked... But as a result of doing this IE plays up and doesn't let you click on any of the content inside the image, hence the js fixes this up.

Comment: Forget table. Forget putting divs inside links. Forget horrible JS ‘fixes’. If you're just trying to avoid the extra line-spacing you get from putting an image in an inline context, set `display: block` or `vertical-align: top` on the images.

Comment: Humm i don't think I made myself clear... The only consitent thing is the hieght and width of the anchor and the fact that the images are going to be smaller than that... Given this condition the images need to be centered (hoth horzontally and vertically) and the text need to be horzontally aligned at the bottom. If you know of another way of doing this whilst still being able to have a anchor around the outside (as I need to mouse hover and click effect)... well I would give you all my points. But I have tried everything and its not posible (it need to work the same across all browsers).

Comment: You don't need an anchor to implement hover/click effects. A `<div>` or even a `<table>` will do just as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like others said, this happens because your markup is invalid. Going a bit deeper, the problem is that when the parser received `<a><div>` in its input, it may mean two things:

1. You forgot to close the anchor tag, in which case this should become `<a></a><div>...` in the DOM, or
2. The anchor wraps the div, in which case the DOM should be `<a><div></div></a>`.

The correct decision can be made only when more (potentially much more) characters are known; the parsing, as you could have noticed, happens incrementally -- i.e. you can see parts of the page before it's fully downloaded.

Unfortunately, the Mozilla's HTML parser (as of Firefox 3.6 and earlier) is non-deterministic in this case -- the resulting DOM depends on the portions your HTML is split into, while going over network.

There's [a Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414418) about a problem that looks very similar to yours.

I'm sorry for you, and I don't know how to implement (nor have any desire to try implementing ;) the solution to your original problem, but perhaps a hack involving setting `innerHTML` (to avoid parser non-determinism) is in order?

BTW, it would be interesting to check how the HTML5 parsing algorithm says your markup should be treated, since that's what will eventually be implemented in the browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is the answer I was looking for and seems to address the issues that I have mentioned. I didn't exspect people to fix the implementation just to help me understand what is going on. From some of the feedback here I have been able to adjust the html and replace the divs with spans and this has fixed the issue for the time being. I agree, how html 5 deals with this will be interesting and is something that I will have to keep a close eye on. But by then hopefully there will be a better way all together to solve the core alignment issue.

Comment: @vdhant: HTML 5 parsing is closer than you may think, see http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-parsing/ - it links to the specification you can check and to the information how to test it in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You should not wrap block elements/tags (like `<div>`) in inline tags (like `<a>`). That's asking for trouble.

Comment: see the above comment and I know you "shouldn't" do this but it doesn't exsplain why the render randomly gets out of wack.

Comment: That's exactly what explains why it 'randomly gets out of wack'.

Comment: I'm sorry but I would exspect it to be consitent with what it renders. How can it descide to render it one way one minute and then render it another sometime later... what type of code would they have that would render it two different ways given the same input?

Answer (score 3):

That's because your HTML is invalid. Inline elements can only contain other inline elements and cannot contain block elements.

Browsers encountering HTML which breaks this rule is allowed to do anything at all in order to parse the page (including not displaying the page) and apparently firefox's interpretation of **anything-at-all** is not the same as yours.

Note that you can convert inline elements like `<span>` to a block element by setting it's `display` css property. But I'm not entirely sure if that is legal for an element with additional semantics such as an `<a>` tag. Of course, you could convert those divs to inline elements.

Comment: Ok i get what you are saying but it doesn't exsplain why it isn't consistent... why does it do it to this one and not the others???

Comment: For that, you'll need to ask Firefox devs. Browser bug handling is a black art.

Comment: Lol seems like it... this is the strangest thing I have come across.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to stop putting block elements inside anchors.  It's just too useful:
http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

I developed a workaround which seems to disable progressive rendering and avoid this problem.

I use server-side sniffing to look for "Firefox/3" in the user-agent. If found, I put this right after `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // hack for firefox 3.x progressive rendering pessimism
      document.body.style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

And this right before `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.body.style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

In testing, I found that simply inserting an empty `<script>` tag after the body tag avoided the issue I was experiencing.  But it feels more correct and safer doing a show/hide.

Hard to know for sure what FF is really thinking - I'm curious to know whether this solves the problem for others.

I'm used to doing this sort of thing for IE.  FF3.x is vying for my new least-favorite browser award.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me