# Fix for wrapping block content with anchor tags in Firefox >=3.5

Tags: firefox, html

Anchor tags have historically only been allowed to contain inline content.

HTML5 specifically allows for anchor tags to contain block-level content, and modern versions of Opera/Chrome/Safari implement this behavior correctly, but Firefox does not.

This problem has been previously identified by [others on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891957/how-to-code-anchor-tags-as-block-element-to-contain-other-block-elements) and probably the best fix is to only include default-inline tags inside of anchor tags, and then making them `display:block` within the CSS, but this disallows use of the new html5 tags inside of anchors.

Does anyone have a Firefox-specific fix that allows the following to be rendered in Firefox correctly?

```
<a href="some/page.html">
   <article>
      <section>
         <p> Lorem ipsum... </p>
      </section>
      ...
   </article>
</a>
```

If there is a better way to structure the html such that the same end is achieved, that would be ideal, but a CSS-based solution or even vanilla Javascript solution would be great.

Obviously there are many ways to make a `div` clickable as a link using Javascript and `onclick` but this hides the link target and loses some of the semantic value of the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some unobtrusive javascript to add an onClick handler to the anchor elements with display: block containing block elements. Don't edit your HTML5.

FYI, this is fixed in Firefox 4 betas (A full HTML5 parser is implemented.)

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear this has been fixed.  Unfortunately, block-level content inside of an anchor tag also creates a layout problem on FF 3.* (pre-maturely closes the anchor tag, pushing the content outside of it) so just fixing the onclick behavior still leaves the display/rendering problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to hack this to work is to wrap the content inside the anchor with a span element. So your code would look like this:

```
<a href="some/page.html">
   <span>
       <article>
          <section>
             <p> Lorem ipsum... </p>
          </section>
          ...
       </article>
    </span>
</a>
```

This, of course, is not valid HTML5 anymore but if you really need to get this to work, this hack should do it.